# React does not update before another socket.io message

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, socket.io

I have a node.js socket.io server that emits two messages with a 1000 ms delay. The messages are logged fine in the react app, however if I remove the 1000 ms delay, react does not update the first message's state before the second one is received.

The only way I was able to fix this issue was by using a global variable to store the first message. Is there a solution without a global variable?

Server code:

```
const app = express();
const http = require("http");
const server = http.createServer(app);
const { Server } = require("socket.io");

const io = new Server(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: "*",
    },
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    socket.emit("data1", "First data");
    setTimeout(() => {
        socket.emit("data2", "Second data");
    }, 1000);
});

server.listen(3001, () => {
    console.log("listening on *:3001");
});
```

Working react app using global variable:

```
var data1;

export default function Main() {
    const socket = useContext(SocketContext);

    const onData1 = useCallback((data) => {
        console.log("Received data1:", data);
        data1 = data;
    }, []);

    const onData2 = useCallback(
        (data) => {
            console.log("Received data2:", data);
            console.log("Data1 is:", data1);
        },
        [data1]
    );

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("Binding socket listeners...");
        socket.on("data1", onData1);
        socket.on("data2", onData2);
        return () => {
            console.log("Unbinding socket listeners...");
            socket.off("data1", onData1);
            socket.off("data2", onData2);
        };
    }, [socket, onData1, onData2]);

    return <></>;
}
```

[image: Working output]

Not working react app:

```
export default function Main() {
    const socket = useContext(SocketContext);
    const [data1, setData1] = useState("");

    const onData1 = useCallback((data) => {
        console.log("Received data1:", data);
        setData1(data);
    }, []);

    const onData2 = useCallback(
        (data) => {
            console.log("Received data2:", data);
            console.log("Data1 is:", data1);
        },
        [data1]
    );

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("Binding socket listeners...");
        socket.on("data1", onData1);
        socket.on("data2", onData2);
        return () => {
            console.log("Unbinding socket listeners...");
            socket.off("data1", onData1);
            socket.off("data2", onData2);
        };
    }, [socket, onData1, onData2]);

    return <></>;
}
```

[image: Not working output]

Comment: onData2 runs before the asynchronous state update has finished is my guess. That's not an actual issue though because I'll bet if you output `data1` a few milliseconds later, it'll have the value. There's a very simple way to check this: `return <><p>{data1}</p><p>{data2}</p></>` (provided you store the 2nd piece of data in a second state var)

Comment: That is true, however I want to use `data1` inside `onData2` rather than rendering it, so it should not be an empty string.

Comment: If sending both data items in the same socket message isn't a viable solution, you can use `useEffect(() => { if (data1 && data2) ... }, [data1, data2]);`